# Extract plain text from an html file in C

Tags: html, c, function

I am really desperate. I need to extract all html elements including html tags. I want to retain just plain text. I am required to do this in C. I am discouraged to use Regex. If I use  string  functions, it just removes delimiters , not the string inside. I need to create a program which extracts plain text from an html file. Any guide would be appreciated on how to do so. Thanks!

Comment: How many times have you posted this today?

Comment: this is my second post today. I really need a guide on how to do so.

Comment: @user2150773, parsing html files by _definition_ **requires** that you use Regular expressions. It is too laborious to use "regular C".  Remember: "the magic happens **outside** of your comfort zone."

Answer (score 1):

Here's a starting point for you:

```
void remove_html(char* str) {
    char* html_str = str;
    while(*str) {
        if(*html_str == '<')
            while(*html_str && *html_str++ != '>');
        *str++ = *html_str++; 
    }
}

int main() {
  char foo[] = "hello <p>friends<b>!</b></p>";
  remove_html(foo);
  puts(foo);
}
```

It only strips the angular syntax - doesn't do any parsing. Also, it doesn't convert escape characters.

Comment: Thanks! I get the idea of the code.

Comment: I like this, though there is a potential for the nested loop to process beyond the end of html_str, permitting quite a tricky information disclosure vulnerability. May I suggest `while(*html_str++ != '>' && *html_str);`?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue I agree.

Answer (score 0):

If you open up a html file in notepad, you'll find it is plain text (no images or anything).
All tags start with < and end with >, everything else is text. In this way, you can read through the file only once, excluding the characters that appear between < > symbols.

Pseudocode:

```
bool intag=false;
for (i=0;i<filesize;i++) {
    char c = readchar();
    if (c=='<') intag=true;
    if (!intag) writechar(c);
    if (c=='>') intag=false;
```

This logic should work for most cases, though you may have to do some more work to deal with indented text and possibly any javascript on the page.